# how to resize the actionbar icon

Tags: java, android, material-design

Hi I am trying to have an app icon on the action bar. For api level before 21 I am using Theme.Holo.Light and my app icon is set by default.
But for v21 I am using Theme.Material.Light. By default there is no app icon in the actionbar so I am programatically setting the icon like this

```
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar .setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionbar .setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

But with this approach my app icon is appearing bigger than it appeared with Theme.Holo.Light.

How can I set the app icon in actionbar with Material design theme same as the icon that appeared in Theme.Material.Light?

Comment: is your icon in different res density folders?

Comment: yes I copied it into all the drawable folders

Comment: correct resolution sizes for the correct folders?  http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: But size wasn't a problem when I am using theme.holo.light the icon fits perfectly

Comment: could you post your res/ file structure?